# Apache CouchDB {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid json"}

Tags: json, ajax, couchdb

I am trying to create an admin user in CouchDB through an AJAX request. My problem is that I am getting a `{"error": "bad request", "reason":"invalid json"}`.

```
var urlString= "http://IPAddress:5984/_config/admins/alice -d ";
urlString = urlString + "'" + "\"alice\"" + "'";
alert(urlStrting);
xhttp.open('PUT' urlString, true);
xhttp.send();
```

The `alert(urlString)` shows:

```
http://IPAddress:5984/_config/admins/alice -d '"alice"'
```

I am guessing the quotations somehow get messed up when they are sent to CouchDB. I am using VI editor on AWS (Amazon Linux). I have tried changing the double quotes to single quotes as well as with and without escaping. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my problem. It was not with the quotes at all, but rather in how I was sending the request. I was sending the PUT data (password) as part of the URL itself instead of sending it as PUT data. The corrected code is as follows:

```
var urlString= "http://IPAddress:5984/_config/admins/alice";
alert(urlStrting);
xhttp.open('PUT' urlString, true);
xhttp.send(alice);
```